# Validation using loop when entering numbers in array

Tags: c#

Okay so basically i have this code where i need to enter 7 numbers from 0-37 and i dont want any other numbers to be entered, ive tried doing it with if/else statement and do/while but i cant exactly get it right, i want it to go on until u enter 7 numbers from 0-37. How can i do this?

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  int[] numbers = new int[7];
  Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 0-37");

  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Enter {i + 1} number");
    numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: Is my question not clear enough? lol

Comment: You should declare nested loop which will ask user to enter correct number until `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())` will not return the number in the desired interval.

Comment: It's not *focused* enough.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] numbers = new int[7];
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 0-37");

    bool IsGoodNumber(int n) => n >= 0 && n <= 37;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Enter {i + 1} number");
            numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        } while (!IsGoodNumber(numbers[i]));
    }
}
```

Another way would be:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] numbers = new int[7];
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 0-37");

    bool IsGoodNumber(int n) => n >= 0 && n <= 37;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Enter {i + 1} number");
            numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (IsGoodNumber(numbers[i]))
               break;
                
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid number");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the user enter garbage?

Comment: @Orace this is a topic for a separate question

Comment: This question is a C#101 question and should be closed. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Enter {i + 1} number");
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var number) || number < 0 || number > 37)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"invalid number ");
    }
    
     numbers[i] = number;
}
```

Comment: What if the user enter garbage?